# Does POCO c++ lib digest engine supports SHA2 for digest generation?

Tags: poco-libraries

I have been searching for **SHA2 digest genration support** in `POCO` libraries but it is nowhere mentioned in `POCO` documentation for Hashing https://pocoproject.org/slides/060-RandomCrypto.pdf

It has support for all the other Digest generation algorithms like  **SHA1,MD4,MD5** etc. and `HMAC` too for message authentication code but **SHA2 is no where to be found.**

Answer (score 0):

Not in the current release. [SHA2](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/SHA2Engine.h) (unless someone backports it from develop back to 1.x) will be released in 2.0

Comment: We are using Poco 1.9 currently  and  we are able to use SHA2 digest using  Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine but not  Poco::DigestEngine( present in the Foundation), but i can't find it's documentation anywhere, is it supposed to be like this?